# Windows Server 2003 Restarts after bootscreen

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, bsod

Im working with a dell server with windows server 2003, after installing SQL Server, the system restarts after bootscreen everytime.
On options menu (when you press F8) I disabled "restart on failure", the system shows me the following message;

[image: follwing message]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide screenshot that includes entire message. It's cut off on the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

After pressing F8, select the Last Known Good configuration from the startup menu.

**Start the computer using the last known good configuration**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782832%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: I've already tried that, and the problem remains =(

Comment: Restore from backup.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try going into safe mode and uninstall sql u just installed. The Installater service will not be running so you need to use the link below.

http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/windows-installer-safe-mode

If that doesnt work then basically you are not in a good position. Boot from a 2003 CD and goto new installation and when it finds the existing installation, repair it rather than reinstallation. That is the only way i can think at this point to fix this.